# insert a value from a db to textfield in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i'm still beginner in yii and php.

my problem is:

i want add a value that from db to my textfield.
my db table 'config' have 3 column, id;name;value;

i have tried code like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['value'=>$model->value])->label('name',['class'=>'label-class'])?>
```

but it didn't show the value.

i want a update form for change value . example: name: title; value: hello world.

Comment: Show your controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should be something like that:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = Mymodel::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

and in view you simply write

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput()->label('name',['class'=>'label-class'])?>
```

Your database values will be in your field.

For simple CRUD you may use GII http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html